# Hacked Facebook account

Tags: facebook, account-management, hacked

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My account on Facebook has been hacked - how do I recover it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/498/my-account-on-facebook-has-been-hacked-how-do-i-recover-it)

Somebody hacked my Facebook id recently and it's creating a mess in my friend circle.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you still can login to your facebook account, change your password immediately, and moreover if you have used some facebook apps recently revoke the permission given to them.